# High Level Design for billing cycle closure

Tags: algorithm, architecture

I need to build a system for billing cycle closure for millions of users. The system behaves similarly to the credit card billing cycle. The main aim of this system is to close the previous billing cycle(a period for opening and closing a billing statement) and open a new one so, that the new transactions get attached to it. However, here the user has the freedom to change his cycle at any time and it has an immediate effect, i.e., it will affect the current running cycle.
The approach I was thinking of is:

1. At 00:00:00 every day I would run a cron that executes a function.
2. This function essentially updates all the settlements whose closing date is yesterday date to close.
3. Going thru this updated list I construct new settlements(open and close date) based on the user's configuration for the settlement cycle.
4. Insert the newly constructed settlements into the table.

The problem I realize here is that it is not scalable. As and when my users are growing, there are a lot of write operations(steps 2 and 4) and for loop(step 3) that need to be run. So, was wondering how the credit card billing cycle closure works?

Tech stack:
DB - PostgresSQL
Programming Language - Node.js / Java

Comment: Why using dates? Why don't you store a day number from a base, let's say 01/01/2010 (so we're currently day #4484) of the last close/open operation and stores the number of day for the cycle? So each day, you'll have only to compute a very light addition, compare it to current day, and process only these fields... A conditional `SELECT`, a `JOIN` and you can't avoid the close/open operation anyway, but you'll only have to set the day number (period isn't changing).

Comment: We need to use dates because the user has the liberty to choose the dates in a month for opening and closing. Is there any way to perform these operations in an efficient way?

Comment: OK, it's based on the day in month... Still using the day number, calculate (at opening) the closing date as a day number. It's WAY faster to compare (for example) "4484" (today) to "4504" (closing at May, 1st) rather than comparing DD/MM/YYYY dates. You'll do the "complex" date operation/conversion only during REAL close/open operations, and not DAILY for ALL accounts. Then you store this closing date as deadline, and daily, you get all accounts where deadline is greater than "today". If this "deadline" column is properly indexed, it's a really, really fast operation.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. However, this improvises the read, will the update query perform well in case there are millions of records matching the criteria? Also, I am more concerned about the for loop that I need to run to set the close_at field and insert those new settlements to the table. I was checking the bulk insert (which supports only 1000 records per query and COPY FROM 'file' command which just increases the complexity of writting to a file)

Comment: The fact is: if you MUST close/open let's say 100.000 fields, you CAN'T do less than reading/writing these 100.000 tuples... That's why you must do all this in one single SQL statement (don't know well PstgresSQL, sorry) so that you'll alter _ONLY_ the needed tuples: you set the close date to "now", a deadline to "now+period" (date computing) only for tuples where "deadline>=now" (this is your `WHERE` clause). The only other solution would be a total rethink of database, organized around a table containing the close days and linked to accounts through LUTs... Won't be simpler nor faster.